# How Can I Get String Dates from Coredata in Asending or Descending Order in IOS

Tags: iphone, core-data

In My Applicaiton i am inserting dates in coredata as strings.how can i get those dates in asending or descending order.I am using below code for fetching date strings from coredata and displaying results in section table and fetched dates as section titles .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(IBAction)insert:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc=[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext];
    StringDates *entity=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"StringDates" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    entity.unused=insertTextField.text;
    entity.message=@"123456789";
    NSError *error;
    [moc save:&error];
    [insertTextField resignFirstResponder];

}
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext];

    if (moc == nil) return nil;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"StringDates" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSSortDescriptor    *sd1    = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"unused" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors    = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1,nil];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"unused" cacheName:nil];

    [fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];   

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
    }


    return fetchedResultsController;



}
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [stringDatesTableView reloadData];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{  

    return [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] count];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{  

    NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];

    if (section < [sections count])
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:section];

        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
    }

    return 0;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //static NSString *cellidenitifier=@"cell";


    StringDates *userRecentChat=[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=userRecentChat.message;
    return  cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];

    if (section < [sections count])
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:section];
        return sectionInfo.name;

    }
    return @"";
}
```

but Dates strings are not coming either asending order or descendibg order.Can anyone solve my problem.Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a NSDateFormatter object to create NSDate objects and store those into CoreData. Then you could easily sort them ascending/descending by using a NSSortdescriptor.

Just take a quick look into the NSDateFormatter Reference 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And the DateFormattingGuide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i

It's super easy to do.

Comment: I took table feild as NSString.It is difficult change to NSDate

Comment: Well but as far as I know there is no way to compare Dates stored in Strings. I mean Stringcomparison only compares single characters and you cannot apply any logic to that. NSDate Objects instead know how to compare themselves to other dates.

Comment: And in fact changing that is not all that difficult. You just change the core data property from NSString to NSDate and use a NSDateFormatter to change the NSString to NSDate when you store it and another NSDAte Formatter when you want to change the NSDate to NSString.

Comment: Thanks.I am understood what you are saying,but if i change field type application will crash b'coz earlier some data is there in table of type NSString now i am inserting NSDate data.I donot want delete application.

Comment: Well yeah, that's right, you always have to delete the application from the device when you change the CoreDataModel. But why can't you delete the application? That's only a matter of 1-2 minutes. Erase the App from the device, Clean Xcode, Rebuild the App to the device. If you do not want to erase the App from the device you could still use another device or the simulator for testing this solution

Comment: You don't always have to delete the application. There are a variety of migrations that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805589)

In the `compare:` function or the block use `NSDateFormatter` to create `NSDate` objects from `NSString` dates and then return the comparison result. Result of comparison will depend on the sort order you require.

Cheers!
Amar.

Comment: A sort descriptor for a Core Data fetch request can *only* use persistent attributes. Custom (Objective-C based) sort methods do not work with Core Data.

Comment: Make a fetch request based on your criteria which will return you an NSArray. On that array you can use the method described in the link.

Comment: You can to that, but then the automatic table view updates of the fetched results controller do not work anymore.

Comment: Also, NSSortDescriptor will provide you initialize method to accept selector to compare custom objects where you can specify compare: method. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-SW4)

Comment: But you cannot use arbitrary sort descriptors in a Core Data fetch request, see [Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11): *"sort descriptors (or predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot work"*